# Action Button for ShinyR

Tags: html, r, shinydashboard

I'm creating a dashboard using shiny. At present if I've to run the dashboard I've to open server.R or ui.R in RStudio and do "Run App". My question is, is it possible to have an action button within an interface, where I'll click that action button and the dashboard will open? Is there any example for it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Create an rscript called appLauncher.R that loads the rshiny package, then calls the following function, being sure to fill in the directory for your app:

```
runApp(appDir = , launch.browser = TRUE)
```

Then create a shortcut on your desktop to `Rscript c:\aDirectory\appLauncher.R`, updating the path to the script to be appropriate to where you saved it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I already created this "runApp" part. But when I run it it opens in Rstudio and then I've to clicks "Run App" again to run the dashboard. But I wanted one click button or a code which will open the dashboard directly. The whole RStusio will be in the background.

Comment: Thats why I suggested making it a shortcut as stated in the answer, rather than just opening the file which is associated with rstudio.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I'm having confusion regarding shortcut part. So, I've a R code that has appLauncher.R. Then I create code that has Rscript part. I created the shortcut in my desktop for Rscript code. And doubleclick it to run it. But it's opening..not running the app. Now sure where I'm making the mistake.